# Can İ learn playing piano like professional after the age of 20?

Tags: piano

I am now 20 years old. But  untill this moment I could not learn  playing any instrument  because of the circumstances  I was under.But  music was always part of my life.  During my childhood, I just did not realize i should  appreciate my musical talent. I used to sing a lot, and whistle, unfortunately my parents did not realize too.  But as years pass,   this passion never  fades away. It is always the same. I am definitely sure music means much more to me than most of the people.  When I sit in front of the piano, I get excited and I want to expose all the music inside me. But   then I sadly realize I  can't play. The piano  is near to me but at the same time,  far away.

Comment: It might depend on what kind of professional you want to be, but generally it’s never too late.

Comment: You are never too old. It's just that if you started at an early age, then it is much easier to pick up piano. But it's certainly possible to start learning piano at the age of 20.

Comment: I started piano lessons at age 9, and nobody let me forget that it was too late and 4 to 5 would have been the right age.

Comment: You have a piano in front of you. What's to lose? What's to gain? Stop wasting any more time!

Comment: enthusiasm is 90% of success, ask yourself this; "_when I am 40, will I regret not trying piano when I was 20?_" I think the answer will be *YES*, as speaking from personal experience, you will likely have children, a busy job, other cares and zero time. See also https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/41961/getting-back-to-the-piano?rq=1 and https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/105456/am-i-too-old-is-it-too-late-a-guide-to-a-popular-question?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: look on it this way - when you will be 40, you could have already 20 years of playing experience. Generally speaking, you might not become a concert pianist (the one which keeps most demanding pieces in the repertoire, like Liszt's Concerto No. 1). You might want to take a look on any conservatoire's curriculum to see what is possible to play on which level